# Calculating values based on AngularJS Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am implementing the angularJS slider found here:

https://github.com/venturocket/angular-slider

I have the slider(s) working correctly but now need to pull the values from them to perform some simple calculations.

The HTML:

```
<p>I'd like to borrow: {{calculate.amount}}</p>


 <slider floor="100" ceiling="1000" precision="0" ng-model="calculate.amount" translate="currencyFormatting"></slider>

  <p>and pay over a period of {{calculate.length}} months</p>

  <slider floor="12" ceiling="120 months" precision="0" ng-model="calculate.length" translate="monthFormatting"></slider>
```

and in my controller I currently have the following code, including my attempts at getting the sliders current value.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('calculatorCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log('');
    console.log($scope);

    $scope.interestRate = 8.9;
    $scope.calculate = {};
   // $scope.amount = $scope.calculate.amount;

    $scope.costPerMonth = ($scope.calculate.amount / $scope.calculate.length);

   // $scope.loanAmount = parseInt($scope.calculate.amount, 10);



    console.log($scope.loanAmount);

    $scope.currencyFormatting = function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        console.log('currency formatting');
        return value.toString() + " £";
    }

    $scope.monthFormatting = function(value) {
        return '$' + value;

    }

}]);
```

I suspect, and this is purely speculation, that I will need some sort of callback to access the sliders value?

edit:

I am aware that this works in the view:

```
<p>At a cost of {{calculate.amount / calculate.length}} per month</p>
```

however I would like to be able to manipulate these values in the controller!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the communicty controls which are here: https://github.com/angular-ui
bind the slider to a model and then access the values as you would any other control which is two way bound as the directive takes care of the binding for you.